# How to make a PAN faster/slower speed with FFmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have an image named "input.png" 1920x7580 px and i want to make a PAN across it  from top to bottom. My current code is:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i input.png -vf crop=1920:1080:0:n -frames:v 6500 out.mkv
```

My video duration with this default speed is 4:20 (260 second). The scrolling down speed is 25 pixels per second.

How i increase/decrease this speed without changing the video FPS (25 fps)? For example my video duration to be 3 minutes.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your current vertical speed is 1 pixel/frame, as your `y` expr is simply the input frame index `n`.

To fully pan from top of bottom, y should start from `0` and end at `ih-oh`. To complete this pan in `x` seconds, pan speed should be `(ih-oh)/x` per second.

So, for 3 minutes,

`ffmpeg -loop 1 -i input.png -vf crop=1920:1080:0:'t*(ih-oh)/180' -t 180 out.mkv`